# Foreach/per-item iteration in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL and I think I must just be missing something, but I can't find any resources on how to do the following:

I have a table with three relevant columns: id, creation_date, latest_id. latest_id refers to the id of another entry (a newer revision).

For each entry, I would like to find the min creation date of all entries with latest_id = *this.id*. How do I perform this type of iteration in SQL / reference the value of the current row in an iteration?

Comment: Don't think "iteration" when using SQL. 99% of the time, if you're writing any kind of loop in SQL you're making a big mistake. Instead, think of an operation applied to a set. And instead of doing these operations in sequence, nest them or use a CTE.

Comment: Also: what database and version are you using? The exact syntax here can change a bit depending on what you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* solve this with a loop, but it's not anywhere close the best strategy. Instead, try this:

```
SELECT tf.id, tf.Creation_Date
FROM 
(
    SELECT t0.id, t1.Creation_Date, 
        row_number() over (partition by t0.id order by t1.creation_date) rn
    FROM [MyTable] t0 -- table prime
    INNER JOIN [MyTable] t1 ON t1.latest_id = t0.id -- table 1
) tf -- table final
WHERE tf.rn = 1
```

This connects the `id` to the `latest_id` by joining the table to itself. Then it uses a windowing function to help identify the smallest Creation_Date for each match.

Comment: Thanks Joel! I had a feeling thinking about it as a loop was incorrect, still getting used to the paradigm.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
    t.id, min(t2.creation_date) as min_creation_date
from 
    mytable t 
    left join 
    mytable t2 on t2.latest_id = t.id
group by 
    t.id
```

Comment: This is better than my answer if creation_date is the only field you need. I've gotten used to needing more than one field and wanting to be sure they come from the same row ;)

Comment: you could add additional columns to the group and be assured they "come from the same row", but the OP gave no other columns to work with.

Comment: If you add additional columns from the aggregated set, they might be sourced from different rows. For example, you could also put `max(t2.creation_date)` in the same query, and those are very unlikely to be the same. Or say we also had a `description` field. If you also wanted to know the description that corresponds with the minimum date, `MIN(description)` is not good enough. In that case, the window function solution is better. But as that's not part of the actual question I gave you the credit and the upvote.

Comment: Ah, yes I see what you are saying.